# PODMAN: Execute a bash script inside the podman container from outside

Tags: linux, bash, containers, podman

I'm trying to run a bash script "init.sh" inside a podman container. The mentioned script runs some builds inside the container. I want to execute this script inside the container without entering the container.
Any leads?

I have tried the following command.

sudo podman exec -it GHC-container /path_to_script.sh

Comment: you probably don't need the "sudo" if you are running rootless. Assuming the container is already running, that seems about right to me. Do you get an error?

Comment: Thanks for the response, @RichardHuxton.
I get the following error:

 no such file or directory: OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found

Comment: Just checking - `/path_to_script.sh` *is* the path to the script as viewed from inside the container, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, @RichardHuxton
The path to the script was according to as viewed from inside the container, but it was a little bit off. Correcting the path resolved it.
Thanks again.